# Deploy ActiveMQ Artemis example without Maven

Tags: java, maven, activemq-artemis

I am testing and learning ActiveMQ Artemis.

I am able to run sample code examples provided with Artemis deployment using `maven`.

A successful example deployment such as:

```
G:\apache-artemis-2.6.0\examples\features\standard\large-message> \apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\mvn.cmd -P noServer verify
```

The sample works well, and I understand the code.

**The problem is:** How to deploy an example code without `maven`. I need to find out the `classpath` and other `JVM` options used by `maven` when deploying an example code.

I tried to run **`-X`** option with `maven` to get the detailed debug output. But it did not assist me in identifying the final deployment `JVM` options/configuration.

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- artemis-maven-plugin:2.6.0:runClient (runClient) @ large-message ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.activemq:artemis-maven-plugin:2.6.0:runClient from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.activemq:artemis-maven-plugin:2.6.0,
parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-maven-plugin:2.6.0:runClient' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) args = [G:\apache-artemis-2.6.0\examples\features\standard\large-message/target/server0, true]
[DEBUG]   (f) clientClass = org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.example.LargeMessageExample
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///C:/Users/davidma/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepos = [apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/, default, releases+snapshots), central (https://repo.mave
n.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG]   (f) repoSession = org.eclipse.aether.DefaultRepositorySystemSession@5a96f3cb
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
args[0]=G:\apache-artemis-2.6.0\examples\features\standard\large-message/target/server0
args[1]=true
[DEBUG] Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
[DEBUG] Platform: Windows
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
[DEBUG] Java version: 8
[DEBUG] sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
[DEBUG] sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
[DEBUG] java.nio.Buffer.address: available
[DEBUG] direct buffer constructor: available
[DEBUG] java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
[DEBUG] jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable prior to Java9
[DEBUG] java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): available
[DEBUG] sun.misc.Unsafe: available
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\davidma\AppData\Local\Temp\3 (java.io.tmpdir)
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: 7635730432 bytes
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
[DEBUG] java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 48
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
[DEBUG] org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.processId: 29964 (auto-detected)
[DEBUG] -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
[DEBUG] -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
[DEBUG] Loopback interface: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1, 127.0.0.1)
[DEBUG] Failed to get SOMAXCONN from sysctl and file \proc\sys\net\core\somaxconn. Default: 200
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.machineId: 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:e0 (auto-detected)
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 48
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 48
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: true
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
[DEBUG] -Dio.netty.buffer.bytebuf.checkAccessible: true
[DEBUG] Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@17d0d3d7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run `maven` to find the classpath used to run the example. The classpaths are very simple.

The broker itself manages its own classpath and JVM properties so all you need to do is start the broker in a normal fashion (e.g. using `./artemis run`).

As for the client application, the only jar it needs on the classpath is the `artemis-jms-client-all-<version>.jar` shipped with the broker in the `lib/client` directory. It doesn't require any specific JVM properties.

Comment: thanks for the advise, what about other undocumented  `JVM` properties required by the client?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!